# Is it possible to render my chrome extension UI before the DOM or html is ready?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension that has a sidebar on the page. Every time the user opens a new tab or loads a new page, there is a delay between the action and rendering of the new page.

I would like to create the effect that my extension sidebar persists between page loads and is instantly ready when the user opens a new tab.

My content scripts runs at document_start and will run before the document finishes loading and renders. I'm just wondering if I can render my UI before the original html finishes its own process?

```
const extensionContainer = document.createElement('div')
extensionContainer.id = 'chrome_extension' //Some hash
document.documentElement.appendChild(extensionContainer);

//Render react component
ReactDOM.render(<App />, extensionContainer)
```

The above code works but is still rendered when the document is fully loaded creating a delayed effect.

Perhaps I can do two renders. The first render after content script injects the sidebar and then render when the requested HTML has finished loading.

Can I do some trickery like delaying the html fetch, render my sidebar, then immediately after continue the normal html fetch process? This way even if there is a problem with the server, my sidebar will already be rendered.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Until the question is edited properly, I'll venture a guess: maybe ReactDOM doesn't work when the root node is outside of `<body>`. In that case you'll need to wait for the `body` to be appended using a MutationObserver.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit your extension manifest.json, and use the "run_at" definition with a proper value of "document_start". As in.:

```
...
"content_scripts": [ { 
   //...
    "run_at": "document_start"
} ], // ...
```

Definition:

> > In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.

For further reading [see...>](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: he's not doing it properly.